# How can I configure SOAP XML namespaces in web service client request?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I am having trouble calling a 3rd party web-service.  I have *not* received a SOAP fault, but am *not* getting a valid resultset.  A colleague of mine has written a client in RPG on the OS400 and it returns a valid resultset.  When comparing the RAW request in Fiddler2 for both requests, the only glaring difference I noticed was that my c# client had SOAP xml elements with **xmlns=""** and his did not.  Is it possible to remove said empty namespace declarations?  Please see the referenced SOAP request below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <SendArchitectServiceRequest xmlns="archserver.xsd.dataflux.com">
            <serviceName xmlns="">AddressVerify.dmc</serviceName>
            <fieldDefinitions xmlns="">
                <fieldName>AddressLine_1</fieldName>
                <fieldType>STRING</fieldType>
                <fieldLength>255</fieldLength>
            </fieldDefinitions>
            <fieldDefinitions xmlns="">
                <fieldName>AddressLine_2</fieldName>
                <fieldType>STRING</fieldType>
                <fieldLength>255</fieldLength>
            </fieldDefinitions>
            <fieldDefinitions xmlns="">
                <fieldName>City_in</fieldName>
                <fieldType>STRING</fieldType>
                <fieldLength>255</fieldLength>
            </fieldDefinitions>
            <fieldDefinitions xmlns="">
                <fieldName>State_in</fieldName>
                <fieldType>STRING</fieldType>
                <fieldLength>255</fieldLength>
            </fieldDefinitions>
            <fieldDefinitions xmlns="">
                <fieldName>Zip</fieldName>
                <fieldType>STRING</fieldType>
                <fieldLength>255</fieldLength>
            </fieldDefinitions>
            <fieldDefinitions xmlns="">
                <fieldName>Country</fieldName>
                <fieldType>STRING</fieldType>
                <fieldLength>255</fieldLength>
            </fieldDefinitions>
            <dataRows xmlns="">
                <value>3485 W. Harmon Ave.</value>
                <value/>
                <value>Las Vegas</value>
                <value>NV</value>
                <value>89103</value>
                <value>United States</value>
                <reserved>0</reserved>
            </dataRows>
        </SendArchitectServiceRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: If I alter the auto-generated Reference.cs class XML element declarations from [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] to [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)] the empty namespace declarations go away.  Is there a way to do this without modifying this volatile, auto-generated file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed method seems like the easiest approach. One other approach would be to use [SOAP extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) to modifiy the SOAP response, removing the empty xmlns attribute. You would modify the [SoapClientMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapclientmessage.aspx) in the `BeforeDeserialize` stage of the [SoapMessageStage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapmessagestage.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not heard any comments or answers to my second question, I will accept the answer I came across which was altering the auto-generated Reference.cs class XML element declarations from `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)` to `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)`.